# requires перед и после названия функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, concept

```
template<typename T> requires true void f() {}
template<typename T> void f() requires true {}
```

В чём разница между этими функциями?

Comment: Голос за закрытие с причиной "домашнее задание"? Серьезно?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, разница в том, что в первом случае `requires` относится к объявлению шаблона, а во втором случае — к функции. Судя по всему, семантической разницы между ними нет, а чисто синтаксически можно даже написать что-то вроде:

```
template<typename T> requires (true)
void f() requires (false) {} // бессмысленно, но компилируется
```

Но, например, при объявлении функций-членов шаблонного класса возможна только вторая форма:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> requires (true)           // ОК
class t {
    void bar() requires (std::is_void_v<T>) {} // ОК
//  requires (std::is_void_v<T>) void baz() {} // Ошибка
};

int main() {
    t<void> t_v;                               // ОК
    t<int> t_i;                                // ОК

    t_v.bar();                                 // ОК
//  t_i.bar();                                 // Ошибка
    return 0;
}
```